# Inner joining a table twice to another table - sqlite

Tags: sqlite

grateful for your help.  I have two tables and I would like to inner join one table to another twice.

```
CREATE TABLE "indexlist" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "word"  UNIQUE
)

INSERT INTO "indexlist" (words) VALUES
    ( 'run' ),
    ( 'hand' ),
    ( 'man' ),
    ( 'far' )

CREATE TABLE "nodes" (
    "source"    TEXT,
    "Target"    TEXT
)


INSERT INTO nodes ( source, target ) VALUES
    ( "run", "far" ),
    ( "far", "hand" );
```

I have tried this.  It does not throw up an error message, but it does not show any results:

```
SELECT t.id, t.word, 
   t1.target, t2.source
FROM indexlist t
LEFT JOIN nodes t1 ON t1.target=t.word
LEFT JOIN nodes t2 ON t.word=t2.source
```

I would like to output the following table:

```
source_id | source | target | target_id
=======================================
1         | run    | far    |         4

4         | far    | hand   |         2
```

Comment: This is not quite how stackoverflow works. I suggest you show us what you have tried, and what you are struggling with.

Comment: Yes, it ignored most of my input first time round for some reason.  Now edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join use a `LEFT` join of `nodes` to 2 copies of `indexlist`:

```
SELECT i1.id source_id, n.source, n.target, i2.id target_id
FROM nodes n
LEFT JOIN indexlist i1 ON n.source = i1.word
LEFT JOIN indexlist i2 ON n.target = i2.word
```

Results:

```
source_id source    Target  target_id
1         run       far     4
4         far       hand    2
```

Comment: Actually, your approach works perfectly with inner join too - thanks!  I couldn't use left join as I wanted to avoid the null values.

Comment: If there is always a match then use INNER JOIN. I used LEFT JOIN just like your code for the case that there is not always a match for both source and target.

Comment: Good point, should have clarified in my question that the values in 'nodes' would always be contained in the 'indexlist' values too, and therefore INNER JOIN would be most appropriate.  Thanks again!